# Upload using twine in appveyor using PS

Tags: python, pypi, appveyor

In my deploy script on AppVeyor I use the `ps: >-` command to deploy depending on the repo branch:

```
- ps: >-
    If ($env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH -eq 'devel') { 
        echo not deploying on devel # twine upload --skip-existing -r test dist/*
    }
    ElseIf ($env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH -eq 'deploy') {  
        twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
    }
    Else {
        echo not deploying on other branches
    }
```

This creates an error message on the AppVeyor build like the following:

```
twine : 
At line:2 char:5
+     twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

And the build shows as failed. Weirdly the packages get uploaded to pypi and are available for download. Thus the command actually performs fine, but the build shows as failed because of this exception. If only the error message would be more informative...

Below another run with a simpler script and the full output as seen on AppVeyor (https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mzwiessele/gpy/build/1.0.361/job/baimi4og179tk3p8)

```
if ($env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH -eq 'deploy') {  
    twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
} else {
    echo not deploying on other branches
}
twine : 
At line:2 char:5
+     twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  0%|          | 0.00/1.21M [00:00<?, ?bytes/s]
  1%|          | 8.19K/1.21M [00:00<00:21, 56.1Kbytes/s]
  8%|8         | 98.3K/1.21M [00:00<00:14, 77.6Kbytes/s]
 33%|###3      | 401K/1.21M [00:00<00:07, 109Kbytes/s]  

  0%|          | 0.00/1.43M [00:00<?, ?bytes/s]

Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading GPy-1.7.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Uploading GPy-1.7.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
Command executed with exception:
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `twine` writes output to StdErr and any output to StdErr is considered as `RemoteException` by PowerShell host. Try re-writing that PS command as batch file.